# Why does this bootstrap layout grid wrap when it should not?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

(Note: This site only works with Chrome, IE will not display it as it does not support the Fetch spec yet)

http://greggum.com/#/entity-shell/entityDetails/14

If you go to this page, there is a row with two child divs that should both fit on one row. One has a class of `col-sm-8` and the second `col-sm-4`  But instead, the second wraps below the first.

The issue is with the splitter that is used on the page.  If I remove the splitter, then it works ok.  But I don't know what to do to resolve.

It also works if I change the second one to `col-sm-3` But then it does not fill the entire area.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Please include enough code in the question itself to successfully recreate the issue you're having when you're seeking debugging help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but this fixed the issue:

```
.row div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This is because changing `box-sizing` affects the way the box model of elements works. By using `border-box`, the padding is taken from the total width declared instead of adding to it, which was causing the wrapping

Comment: Thank you.  If you want to post this as the answer, I will accept.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to fix it.

change

```
<div class="row">
```

to

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

courtesy: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/08/why-use-the-bootstrap-grid.aspx

Comment: I don't think there is a `.row-fluid` class in Bootstrap, or is that a custom one?